# Math doesn't work for the size and position of Game Pieces WRT the size of their container "room"

Tags: swift, image, position

**The positions and sizes of my Game Pieces, as set by `CGPoint(..)` and `CGRect(..)`, don’t make arithmetic sense to me when looked at with respect to the width and height of the surrounding container of all Game Pieces?**

Let me illustrate with just one specific example –

I call the surrounding container = “room”.

One of many specific Game Pieces = “rock”.

Here’s the math

```
roomWidth  = Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
roomHeight = Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

While in Portrait mode:

```
roomWidth = 744.0
roomHeight = 1133.0
```

When rotated to Landscape mode:

```
roomWidth = 1133.0, 
roomHeight = 744.0
```

So far so good .. **here’s the problem:**

**When I look at my `.sks` file**, the width of the “rock” and its adjacent game pieces far exceeds the roomWidth; for example,

Widths of rock + paddle + tree = 507 + 768 + 998 which obviously exceeds the room’s width for either Portrait or Landscape mode – and this math doesn’t even address the separation between Game Pieces.

The final math “craziness” looks at the swift xPos values for each Game Piece as specified in my `.sks` file:

```
Room: xPos = 40, 
Rock: xPos = -390, 
Paddle: xPos = -259, 
Tree: xPos = 224
```

I cannot grasp the **two high negative numbers** .. to me, that means the Rock and the Paddle shouldn’t even be visible .. seriously off-screen.

One significant addition = I did set the `Autoresizing Mask` to center horizontally and vertically

[image: Autoresizing Mask]

I need a serious infusion of “smarts” here.

Answer (score 0):

The default [`anchorPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519864-anchorpoint) of an [sks file](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/creating_a_scene_from_a_file) (SpriteKit Scene file) is (0.5, 0.5). So the origin (0, 0) of the scene is drawn at the center of the `SKView`. You can change the anchor point in the Attributes inspector when editing the sks file. The default means that negative coordinates not too far from the origin will be visible in the `SKView`.

The scene also has a [`scaleMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519562-scalemode) property which determines how the scene is scaled if its size doesn't match the `SKView`'s size. The default is `.fill`, which means the view scales the scene's axes independently so the scene's `size` exactly fills the view.

Comment: `anchorPoint` and `scaleMode` recommendations were already implemented in my `sks` File before I posted my question. The negative numbers I mentioned in the OP I think point to the root cause; I just wish I knew what that cause is. **BTW**, I believe that the `scaleMode` spec applies to the `SKScene` not the individual Game Pieces inside that "room". The `anchorPoint` spec is applied to all the `SKSpriteNode` Game Pieces inside it.